# Nginx/php-fpm umask setting

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, permissions

When I was using apache2 server, setting default `umask` in /etc/apache2/envvars to `0002` used to solve all my permissions problems. Now that I am trying to setup nginx/php-fpm, I have come across the same problems when files are created with improper permissions.

Is there `umask` setting in nginx or php-fpm?

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to [Blossoming_Flower's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43130436/623519) and an [answer on unix.stackechange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398540/how-to-override-systemd-unit-file-settings)...

The best way seems to do as Blossoming _Flower says, but do it with an **override** file instead of editing a system file that may get replaced by a reinstall/upgrade by your distribution.

To do this you do (I'm on php 7.0 but adjust for your version)

```
systemctl edit php7.0-fpm.service
```

which will automatically create (or edit if already exists) a file at `/etc/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service.d/override.conf`.

You can put Blossoming_Flower's suggested content on its own in that file. Systemd will then overwrite the distribution's settings with this one, in effect adding a umask setting.

Then just `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart php7.0-fpm` and you're done.

Answer (score 9):

Taken from the other answer's linked question:

if you use systemd [i.e. Ubuntu 16.04], then edit **/lib/systemd/system/php5-fpm.service**
And edit chapter "Service":

```
[Service]
UMask=0002
```

Comment: It's best not to change service files themselves. Or the changes would be lost one day, when corresponding package would be updated. Override settings via `/etc/systemd/system/<service>.service.d` [dirs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37299891/52499).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to resolve this for myself by adding `umask 0002` to `/etc/init/php-fpm.conf` (**not** `/etc/init.d/php-fpm`). See [How to trace where php5-fpm umask settings are coming from on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248904) for an explanation.