# How to set umask for php5-fpm on Debian?

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I'm running `php5-fpm` with `nginx` connected via port (not socket). It's stock Debian Jessie with all packages installed via `apt-get`.

I'm trying to change default umask for www-data user that `php5-fpm` is using from `0022` to `0002` to allow group write permissions. I've tried:

- editing `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` init script and adding `--umask 0002` to the `start-stop-daemon` call, but it was ignored;
- adding `umask 0002` to `/var/www/.profile` as `/var/www` is a home directory for `www-data` user, but it didn't help (I'm not surprised).
- I'm not using `upstart` so [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319941/899092) is not for me.

Also, no matter what I've tried, the command `sudo -u www-data bash -c umask` always returns `0022`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to set the umask for `php5-fpm` service by editing it's `unit.service` file as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/582380/162374) and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/764296/162374). The complete and working solution for Debian 8 is this:

1. Manually edit `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php5-fpm.service` file and add `UMask=0002` line inside `[Service]` section.
2. Run command `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Run command `systemctl restart php5-fpm.service`

Now the service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description = The PHP FastCGI Process Manager
After = network.target

[Service]
Type = notify
PIDFile = /var/run/php5-fpm.pid
ExecStartPre = /usr/lib/php5/php5-fpm-checkconf
ExecStart = /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
ExecReload = /bin/kill -USR2 $MAINPID
; Added to set umask for files created by PHP
UMask = 0002

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Note that:

1. You can not use `systemctl edit php5-fpm.service` command as `edit` option was introduced in `systemctl` version 218 but Debian 8 ships with version 215.
2. Adding `*.conf` file as suggested in comments for this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/582380/162374) did not work for me, but maybe I messed up something (comments are welcome for this as editing unit file is not something that I feel comfortable with).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Adding a `.conf` file does not work because of an error. Instead of `php-fpm.service` you have to write `php5-fpm.service`. I think it is better to add a `.conf` file like this http://serverfault.com/questions/582371/how-to-set-umask-for-php-fpm-in-fedora/582380#582380