# umask changes occasionally for www-data user

Tags: php, linux, debian

I run PHP with FPM on nginx. This is how I set up [umask for php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36071034/899092).

Occasionally some files written by `www-data` user have `0644` permissions instead of expected `0664` that I should receive with umask set to `0002`. This happens for random files (sometimes for directories too).

Default umask for PHP and FPM combo on Debian is `0022` but my server is set up with `0002`. Yet somehow the same line of PHP code sometimes writes `0664` and sometimes `0644` files.

```
file_put_contents($file, serialize($res));
```

I even added `chmod()` line just to make sure but without luck. And it seems random.

```
file_put_contents($file, serialize($res));
chmod($cacheFile, 0666 & ~umask());
```

The same thing happens for directories that get `0755` instead of `0775`.

How can I prevent that?