# set php-fpm umask in systemd

Tags: php, cakephp, systemd

I have looked at several other answers and none of them are working.  for example:  [How to set umask for php5-fpm on Debian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851049/how-to-set-umask-for-php5-fpm-on-debian)

here's the setup.

I have a cakePHP 2 app running with apache as a reverse proxy for php-fpm on RHEL 7.

I've created a site specific user, which we'll call siteuser.

The virtual host for this site will do a 'SuexecUserGroup for the siteuser user/group.

I've added the php-fpm user to the siteuser group.

There are specific directories in cakePHP 2 which must be writable.  I've made these directories group writable and set the S bit so new files are created with the group intact.

In addition, I set the systemd UMask for php-fpm as follows:

/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/override.conf

```
[Service]
UMask=113
```

After saving this file I do a systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart php-fpm.

however, the files are getting written as 777 rather than the 664 I would expect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add a `0` to your umask for the *special permissions bit* (i.e. sticky, setuid, setgid, etc.)

```
[Service]
UMask=0113
```

**Update**:

It seems like your changes are not being recognized *at all*...
I just noticed you are setting this in your `override.conf` file. In this case you need to make sure that `override.conf` is being included from the main config (IIRC: `php5-fpm.service.conf` in the same folder).

Also, have a look at this [serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/582371/how-to-set-umask-for-php-fpm-in-fedora) that may contain further information for you.

Comment: I made the requested change, but it's still creating files as 777.  Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I eventually came back to this and was able to get the umask working as you recommended.